# Selective error logging (based on error code) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, errors

I want to log all *PostgreSQL* errors except `unique_violation` (error code [`23505`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html)), which I would like suppressed.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You cannot, unless you wrap it into exception handling logic, which is expensive.  You can change your logic to avoid these as much as possible, or just ignore them.  Also, you can possibly post-process log files to remove these.